# Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)-2f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x}{4})=x^{2}$ . Then $f(3)$ =?

Tags: functional-equations

Options: (a)$4$,    (b)$4f(0)$,       (c)$4-f(0)$,        (d)$4+f(0)$,   (e)$16+f(0)$.

---

`CORRECT ANSWER USING REDUCTION`

> Deep thanks to @martini and @A.S. , soo much respect .

Since we don't exactly know the nature of $f(x)$ we will start of by considering our function as  $f(x)=g(x)+cx^2$ where $g(x)$ represents all the other functions (including constant values) inside $f(x)$ and $cx^{2}$ includes the no. of $x^{2}$ terms.

Now we have $cx^{2}-2\frac{cx^{2}}{4}+\frac{cx^{2}}{16}=x^{2}$

Comparing coefficients of $x^{2}$ in first equation we have $c=\frac{16}{9}$.

And

$g(x)-2g(\frac{x}{2})+g(\frac{x}{4})=0$

Now to solve this recurring equation we substitute $x=\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{4},\frac{x}{8}......$ and add it up .

Yielding $g(\frac{x}{2^i})=ig(\frac{x}{2})-(i-1)g(x)$

Now as $i\to\infty$. Since $g$ is continuous we will have

$g(x)=g(x/2)$.

Now solving the recurring equation $g(x)-g(x/2)=0$ by substituting $x=\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{4},\frac{x}{8}......$ and adding it up .

Now as $i\to\infty$. Since $g$ is continuous we will have

$g(x)=g(0)$

Hence $f(3)=g(3)+(16/9)3^2$.

Now as $g(3)=g(0)= f(0)-(16/9)0^2$.

We finally have $f(3)=f(0)+16.$

Comment: Can you start with $$f(y)=g(y)+a+by+cy^2+dy^3$$  and find immediately that $d=0$  and find  $a,b,c$ such that $$g(y)-2g(y/2)+g(y/4)=0$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+f%28x%29-2f%28x%2F2%29%2Bf%28x%2F4%29%3Dx%5E2

Comment: This question has nothing to do with functional analysis.....

Comment: how $d=0$ , can we find the function from this by some sort of magic substitution ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not given that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @A.S. Oh , i forgot to type that yes its given that its continous but still $f(x)$ could be anything right

Comment: $$\text{(e)}\quad 16+f(0)$$

Comment: Couldn't help myself from posting the solution since i cant add the answer too , a very beautiful problem on its own .

Answer (score 7):

Let $x = 3\cdot 2^{-n}$, giving 
$$ f(3\cdot 2^{-n}) = 9 \cdot 2^{-2n} + 2 f(3 \cdot 2^{-(n+1)}) - f(3 \cdot 2^{-(n+2)}) $$
Write brevitatis causa $a_n := f(3 \cdot 2^{-n})$, we have
$$ a_{n+2} - 2a_{n+1} + a_n = 9 \cdot 2^{-2n} $$
The general solution of the homogenous recursion 
$$ a_{n+2} - 2a_{n+1} + a_n = 0 $$
is $$ a_n^{\text{hom}} = \alpha n + \beta $$
to find a solution of the inhomogenous equation, we make the ansatz  $\gamma \cdot 2^{-2n}$, giving 
$$ \gamma 2^{-2n}(2^{-4} - 2\cdot 2^{-2} + 1) = 9 \cdot 2^{-2n} \iff \gamma = 16 $$
So we have 
$$ f(3 \cdot 2^{-n}) = a_n = 16\cdot 2^{-2n} + \alpha n + \beta $$
for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbf R$. As $f$ is continuous, we must have $a_n \to f(0)$. As $16\cdot 2^{-2n}$ converges, this implies $\alpha = 0$, or 
$$ f(3 \cdot 2^{-n}) = 16 \cdot 2^{-2n} + \beta $$
For $n \to \infty$ this gives $f(0) = \beta$, or 
$$ f(3 \cdot 2^{-n}) = 16 \cdot 2^{-2n} + f(0) $$
for $n=0$ we have
$$ f(3) = 16 + f(0) $$

Comment: If I let $x = 3$ (as we want to find $f(3)$), we get 
$$ f(3) = \text{some term with $f(3/2)$, $f(3/4)$} $$
so to find $f(3)$, we have to find $f(3/2)$. That is, we now let $x = 3/2$. Giving us some term with $f(3/4)$ and $f(3/8)$. So, in general, we have values of $f$ at $3\cdot 2^{-n}$ for different values of $n$. That means, using $x = 3\cdot 2^{-n}$, we get a recursion for $a_n = f(3\cdot 2^{-n})$.

Comment: +1. This approach shows that, for every $x$, $$f(x)=f(0)+\tfrac{16}9x^2.$$

Comment: $a_n$ is just a shortcut for the value $f(3 \cdot 2^{-n})$, which is a real number.

Comment: @martini I tried doing halfway with A.S.'s process by assuming another function $g(x)$ but when i find $g(3)$ and substitute it I'm getting another answer , i think I'm going wrong somewhere , could you please correct me ?   Here is what I've done  http://i.stack..com/j9ryq.jpg

Comment: Your link does not work

Comment: @martini http://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ryq.jpg

Comment: You dropped a two in the $\vdots$-step.

Comment: @martini where precisely ? I have actually added up all the equations and 4 terms get partially cancelled out and two terms remain as such

Answer (score 0):

Look for a simple solution first to "homogenize" the equation. $f(x)=cx^2$ works for $c=16/9$. That means that $g(x)=f(x)-cx^2$ satisfies $g(x)-2g(x/2)+g(x/4)=0$. Rewriting $g(x/4)=2g(x/2)-g(x)$ and iterating yields $$g(x/2^i)=ig(x/2)-(i-1)g(x)$$ Take $i\to\infty$. Since $g$ is continuous at $0$, we must have $g(x)=g(x/2)=g(0)$. Hence $f(x)=f(0)+(16/9)x^2$. Hence $$f(3)=f(0)+16.$$

Comment: Why does the continuity of $g$ at $0$ imply that $(i+1)g(x/2^i)-ig(x/2^{i+1})\to g(0)$?

Comment: Because $x/2^i\to 0$.

Comment: But the prefactors $i+1$ and $i$ explode, right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The right side has $x^2$ so I tried to guess something similar looking on the left.

Comment: 1.Express $g(x/8)$ in terms of $g(x/2)$ and $g(x)$, notice the pattern and use induction. 2. I got $g(x)=g(0)$ and then set $f(0)=g(0)$.

Comment: @A.S. Yea but on solving im getting $g(x)=g(\frac{x}{2})$ only when we divide both sides by $i$ and then apply limits only $g(x),g(\frac{x}{2})$ terms remain